# XCode: potential leak of an object stored into 'cgImage'

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, cgimage

I am getting a " potential leak" warning when I run Analyze. It's related to the line below. I am using ARC, though I understand that a CGImage is not released under ARC.

```
 textureColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:texture];
```

I tried to release it with: `CGImageRelease((__bridge CGImageRef)(textureColor));` but still have the same issue. Any tips on how to take care of this issue?

Comment: You need to provide a little more context, e.g. how was `texture` defined?

Comment: `CGImageRelease((__bridge CGImageRef)(textureColor));` doesn't make any sense - textureColor is not a `UIImage*` or `CGImageRef`. It's a `UIColor` instance and it should be auto released. Show us more code surrounding this line and relating to this object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This color information is used for cache to apply another place. So it doesn't get release I know it is the problem in `UIkit` framework but it does create any problem.